# how to get the url path in jquery json

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery ajax below code,
I had problem with url in the code below `register.aspx` page in `register` folder

```
 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/register/register.aspx/LoadOtherStates',
                data: '{Country_ID: ' + $(this).val() + '}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
```

the register.aspx page in root folder its working fine but my "register.aspx" page in "register" folder in this case url does not find.
how to get the path of the "register.aspx" page  in "register" folder

Comment: Are you able to open Firebug or Webkit Inspector to see what URL is actually being called in the `Network` tab when it fails?

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to just write the absolute path?

`http://www.yoursite.com/register.aspx/LoadOtherStates`

Does this make sense? Your question seems to be unclear.